# Docusign API - trouble with embedded signing

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to use Embedded Signing in the workflow for users on a site I'm building. And the error I consistently get (from the API Explorer and through my own code) is:

> "errorCode": "RECIPIENT_NOT_IN_SEQUENCE",
>   "message": "The token for an out of sequence recipient cannot be generated."

First I'm uploading the document to create an envelope and attaching one recipient:

```
   $data = array(

        'accountId' => $accountId,
        'documents' => array(
            array(
                'documentId' => '1',
                'name' => 'document.pdf'
                )
            ),
        'recipients' => array(
            'signers' => array( array(
                    array(
                        'tabs' => array(
                            'signHereTabs' => array(
                                array(
                                    "pageNumber" => "1",
                                    "documentId" => "1",
                                    "yPosition" => "100",
                                    "xPosition" => "100",
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                'routingOrder'=> '1',
                'recipientId'=> '1',
                'clientUserId'=> $clientUserId,
                'name'=> 'Signer 1',
                'email'=> 'something@gmail.com'
                ))
            )
            );

    $json_data = json_encode($data);

    $file_contents =                 
    file_get_contents("document.pdf");

    $requestBody = "\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."--myboundary\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    ."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."$json_data\r\n"
    ."--myboundary\r\n"
    ."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
    ."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\”document.pdf\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."$file_contents\r\n"
    ."--myboundary--\r\n"
    ."\r\n";

    // *** append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and as signature request endpoint
    $curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
    );
```

And then I'm sending it off to get the recipient url for the Signing View:

```
$data = array("returnUrl" => "http://quidfs.bfclients.com/dashboard",
            "authenticationMethod" => "None",
            "email" => 'something@gmail.com', 
            "userName" => 'Signer 1',
            "clientUserId" => $clientUserId,
        );                                                                    


$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes/$envelopeId/views/recipient" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
            'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
        );
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post a result of `accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients` so we can see that `$clientUserId` is an actual value being passed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see you specifying a status in your request so I'm thinking that might be your issue.  If you do not specify the envelope status when you are creating it I believe the system saves the envelope as a Draft by default instead of sending it immediately.

The two accepted status values are `created` or `sent`.  Setting the status to `created` in turn saves into your Drafts folder to be sent at a later time.  Setting the status to `sent` sends the request immediately.

Try adding that into your request body, something like:

```
$data = array(
    'status' => 'sent',
    'accountId' => $accountId,
    'documents' => array(
        array(
            'documentId' => '1',
            'name' => 'document.pdf'
            )
        ),
    'recipients' => array(
        'signers' => array( array(
                array(
                    'tabs' => array(
                        'signHereTabs' => array(
                            array(
                                "pageNumber" => "1",
                                "documentId" => "1",
                                "yPosition" => "100",
                                "xPosition" => "100",
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
            'routingOrder'=> '1',
            'recipientId'=> '1',
            'clientUserId'=> $clientUserId,
            'name'=> 'Signer 1',
            'email'=> 'something@gmail.com'
            ))
        )
    );
```

Comment: That was it. (adding status=>sent worked) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error

> "errorCode": "RECIPIENT_NOT_IN_SEQUENCE", "message": "The token for an out of sequence recipient cannot be generated."

In my case, I have two recipients, both setting on `'routingOrder'=> '1'` cause my problem! 
First, the signing was necessary to generate the second one token.
I changed on `'routingOrder'=> '0'` and solve my error.

Answer (score 1):

on my case i just set the envelopeDefinition status = "sent" before i call CreateRecipientView

```
        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envDef.Status = "sent";

        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
        Configuration cfi = new Configuration(apiClient);
        string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
        cfi.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
        AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(cfi);
        LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
        string accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(cfi);
        EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

        // 3. Create Envelope Recipient View request obj
        string envelopeId = results.EnvelopeId;
        RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
            ClientUserId = signerClientId,
            AuthenticationMethod = "email",
            UserName = signerName,
            Email = signerEmail
        };

        // 4. Use the SDK to obtain a Recipient View URL
        ViewUrl viewUrl = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, viewOptions)
```